# Creating ListView with Two text in one line

Tags: android

I am creating an application to find near by places from user's current location. I want to create a ListView which will list all the place's name with distance from current location. I am able to to show the place name but how to show the distance in the same list view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am able to to show the place name but how to show the distance in
>   the same list view.

You have to customize ListView.

You can refer sample example here : http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-2

Article from [Vogella.de](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listsactivity_layout)